sudo apt update not working on Ubuntu?
sudo apt update

Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-6-local  InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-6-local  InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  InRelease [1572 B]
Get:3 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-6-local  Release [564 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  InRelease [1572 B]
Get:3 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-6-local  Release [564 B]
Hit:5 nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/deb/amd64  InRelease
Hit:6 developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  InRelease
Hit:7 developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64  InRelease
Hit:8 download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:9 artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable InRelease
Hit:10 download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:11 in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:12 example.com/repo stable InRelease
Hit:13 in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:14 in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:15 in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:12 example.com/repo stable InRelease
Ign:12 example.com/repo stable InRelease
Err:12 example.com/repo stable InRelease
  500  Internal Server Error [IP: 93.184.215.14 80]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done

2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-6-local/Release.gpg: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.

W: developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.

W: download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.

W: download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.

W: in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.

W: in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.

W: in archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.

W: Failed to fetch example.com/repo/dists/stable/InRelease  500  Internal Server Error [IP: 93.184.215.14 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.


Yes, it isn't working because you added "example.com/repo", possibly from some guide meant as an example... It's not an actual repository. Remove it and it should work as it is supposed (all the other warning can be disregarded for now).

@ChanganAuto, that really would be a valid answer; you might make it one.

@DrMoishePippik I agree :-)

This is the problem:
(...)
Err:12 example.com/repo stable InRelease
  500  Internal Server Error [IP: 93.184.215.14 80]
(...)

You added "example.com/repo", possibly from some guide meant as an example but it isn't an actual repository, it's just a placeholder.
Remove it and apt should work as it is supposed (all the other warnings can be disregarded for now).

Thank you solved this, How to solve
Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.

That has to be solved by the 3rd party repositories maintainers. For the moment is just a warning, not a problem.

Removing the Non-Existent Repository Entry:
Open the Sources List File:
Use a text editor like nano or vim to edit the sources list file. The file is typically located at /etc/apt/sources.list or in a file within the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory.
Identify and Remove the Problematic Entry:
Look for the line containing the entry for "example.com/repo" in the sources list file.
Delete or comment out this line by adding a "#" at the beginning of the line.
Save and Exit:
Save the changes you made to the file.
Close the text editor.
Update APT:
After removing the problematic entry, run the following command to update APT and refresh the package cache:
sudo apt update
